# Bivariate correlation across subgroups

Tags: correlation, bivariate, partial-correlation

I have several variables and I would like to test for possible linear correlations between. However, the data is across 2 groups, and there is a significant group difference in these variables. I know I could just correlate within subgroups, but then I would have only half the data points in each subgroup. Would it be valid to use partial correlation instead, with group as factor to adjust for? Any other ideas are welcome.

**Background**
I compare a group of patients with healthy controls in brain activations. I found they differ in 3 areas, so I have extracted these activations values from these regions from both groups. I also have data from 2 psychological tests: memory and learning performance. Thus, I have 3 brain and 2 psychological variables, and the patients showed lower values across all 5 variables compared to controls.

To understand the function of the brain regions, I would like to know if brain activity would show a linear correlation with psychological performance e.g. does the lower activity in one of the regions correlate with the lower performance in one of the tests? One last thing, brain activity in different regions correlate with each other, and so do the two performance scores.

Due to this, I was suggested to simply use multiple bivariate correlations e.g. 3x2=6 and correct for multiple comparisons. All good, I get a lot of significant activation vs performance correlations but I know the significance is inflated due to the patients vs controls group differences. I tested within patients only and the significance is gone. Could be because it is not there, but it could also be because I have half the data points in, e.g. 30 in the patient group instead of 60 across both groups.